# maximum 30 bytes UTF-8 encoding for each keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
validates_format_of :tags, :with => /^(([^,]+),){0,3}([^,]+)$/
```

With this validations possible this regexp:

```
key1, key2, key3, key4
```

However I would like limit the byte number of each keyword to maximum `30`, so this keyword would be possible in regexp:

```
keyword with More than 30 bytes
```

This is specifications link:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_media:keywords

**How I can add this filter to the above regular expression?**

Comment: Do you count spaces as part of the keyword?

Comment: yeahh. These are keywords for youtube api. Youtube allow 30 characters maximum for each keyword :). Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a custom validation for this? If you do that you can just use `split` and check the length of each tag.

Comment: I'd probably use a validation method or custom validator since you'd need to split first, then check length, if *each* item needs to be 30 chars or less. If the *entire* input needs to be less than 30 chars then use the ` length` validator.

Comment: Just in case, this is the actual specification: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_media:keywords

Comment: @nhahtdh, is it correct 30 characters for each word?

Comment: @hyperrjas: No. It is not 30 characters for each word. It is 30 bytes for each word (UTF-8 encoding). This means that if you allow languages other than English, the number of characters allowed is less. There is also this weird rule about spacing, which I am not sure whether the implicit `"` is included in the maximum byte count.

Comment: @nhahtdh, I have edited my question, I have changed bytes instead characters, thank you for this fix.

Comment: @hyperrjas: Please include a link to the specification (and probably quote it). Your description does not really match everything in the specs. This will help you get better answer.

Comment: @nhahtdh I have include specification link and I have edited my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't check it but it should work:

```
validate :length_of_tags

def length_of_tags
  _tags = self.tags.split(',').map {|x| x.strip.force_encoding('utf-8')}
  _tags.each do |tag|
    if tag.bytesize >= 30
      errors.add(:tags, "#{tag} is too long")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems he wants to check the length of each keyword, not the total length of the string.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. Would you please have a look at the specification?

Comment: all you need to do is to check full length and minimum size of 2 bytes

Comment: `tag.bytesize` Does this guarantee to return the number of bytes for UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: you can use `force_encoding` method

Comment: @eru can you add to this code `force_encoding` in your response?. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

(Answers the question, but does not adhere to YouTube specs)

How about this:

```
validates_format_of :tags, :with => /^(([^,]{1,30}),){0,3}([^,]{1,30})$/
```

Comment: This is the actual specification: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_media:keywords I don't think it is doable with regex.

Comment: Yepp. Didn't check it against the specification, only what was given in the question.

Comment: @mdsl, I have edited my question, I'm sorry for the error in my question. Thank you!